# Ways to erase vocals in an audio file

Tags: audio

I have some songs. I wish to separate the instrument sound from the human singing sound. Is it possible to do that? Are there some applications to accomplish that?

Comment: This should be on Audio.SE. I think they did a question like this a while ago, though...

Comment: This question is way under rated.

Answer (score 5):

With professional audio, voice is usually mixed in mono whereas the instruments are mixed in stereo. Subtracting one channel from the other should remove the mono mixing while leaving in the stereo mixing (remixed a bit, of course).

Comment: Thanks! (1) I am still wondering how to do that on computer? (2) More information about stereo mixing and mono mixing please?

Comment: 1) Audacity. 2) A slight delay in one of the channels moves it off-center (i.e. "stereo").

Comment: Thanks! What are some equivalent applications in Ubuntu?

Comment: Audacity. Try your package manager.

Comment: The "Ubuntu Software Center" has Audacity *Featured*, I believe.

Answer (score 4):

[Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) has `Effect->Plugins->Vocal Remover`.

You may need to download the [Nyquist](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/download/nyquistplugins) [plugin](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/download/plugins).

> Vocal Remover requires a stereo track.
>   It works best with lossless files like
>   like WAV or AIFF, rather than MP3 or
>   other compressed formats. It only
>   removes vocals or other audio that is
>   panned to center (sounds equally loud
>   in left and right). Vocals are often
>   mixed this way. Inverting one channel
>   then panning both to center cancels
>   out any audio which was originally
>   center-panned, making it inaudible.
>   This can remove some parts of the
>   audio you may want to keep, such as
>   drums, which are also often mixed to
>   center. If the vocals and other
>   centered parts differ in pitch, this
>   can be solved by removing only
>   selected frequencies.
>
> Vocal Remover thus has three choices
>   of removal method. 'Simple' inverts
>   the entire frequency spectrum of one
>   channel. This may remove too much
>   music if other parts of the audio are
>   centered as well as the vocals. In
>   that case, try the other choices. If
>   the vocals are at a different pitch
>   than the other audio (such as a high
>   female voice), try 'Remove frequency
>   band'. This only removes frequencies
>   between a lower and upper limit which
>   you can enter in the 'Frequency
>   band...' box. Experiment by entering
>   what sounds like the most significant
>   frequency range of the original
>   vocals. If the other choices remove
>   too much audio in a particular
>   frequency range (such as low drums or
>   bass), try 'Retain frequency band'.
>   This only removes frequencies outside
>   the limits entered, retaining the
>   others.

Answer (score 0):

You can also follow [this tutorial to remove vocals from your audio track](https://www.recordingbase.com/extract-vocal-and-instrumental-tracks/).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.